# Decrypt serializable struct is not work

Tags: c#, serialization, encryption, struct

What is my error when trying to decrypt?
When calling DecrypToken shown this message:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: The input stream is not a valid binary format.

[EDIT]
Data now converted data back from the hex format.
Key and IV now is saved to reuse.

Now getting this error:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: End of Stream encountered before parsing was completed.

The code:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace DecryptStruct
{
    class Program
    {
        static byte[] theKey = null;
        static byte[] theIV = null;

        [Serializable]
        internal struct Token
        {
            public string user;
            public string host;
            public string now;
        }

        static string EncryptToken(string user, string host)
        {
            Token token = new Token();

            token.user = user;
            token.now = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            token.host = host;

            //serialize
            IFormatter form = new BinaryFormatter();
            MemoryStream ser = new MemoryStream();
            form.Serialize(ser, (object)token);

            //setup crypto
            Rijndael alg = Rijndael.Create();
            alg.GenerateIV();
            alg.GenerateKey();

            //save keys
            theKey = alg.Key;
            theIV = alg.IV;

            //rewind stream
            ser.Position = 0;

            //encrypt 
            MemoryStream enc = new MemoryStream();
            CryptoStream cw = new CryptoStream(enc, alg.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            cw.Write(ser.ToArray(), 0, (int)ser.Length);
            cw.FlushFinalBlock();

            enc.Position = 0; //rewind
            byte[] benc = enc.ToArray();

            string hex = Convert.ToBase64String(benc);

            cw.Close();

            return hex;
        }

        static Token DecrypToken(string hex)
        {
            byte[] benc = Convert.FromBase64String(hex);

            MemoryStream enc = new MemoryStream(benc);

            //setup crypto
            Rijndael alg = Rijndael.Create();
            alg.Key = theKey;
            alg.IV = theIV;

            CryptoStream cr = new CryptoStream(enc, alg.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read);

            IFormatter form = new BinaryFormatter();
            MemoryStream ser = new MemoryStream();
            form.Serialize(ser, (object)new Token());

            byte[] buf = new byte[(int)ser.Length];
            cr.Read(buf, 0, (int)ser.Length);

            MemoryStream unenc = new MemoryStream(buf);
            unenc.Position = 0;

            //deserialize
            Token tk = (Token)form.Deserialize(unenc);

            return tk;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string enc = EncryptToken("username", "myhost");

            Token token = DecrypToken(enc);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you convert it to hex then you don't convert it back!

Answer (score 2):

You encode it in hex and transform it here:

```
        byte[] benc = enc.ToArray();

        string hex = BitConverter.ToString(benc);

        cw.Close();

        return hex.Replace("-", "");
```

But you don't do the reverse!

Answer (score 2):

The `GenerateIV()` and `GenerateKey()` methods initialize the algorithm with a new, random IV and key respectively. You must use the exact same key and IV to decrypt the data as was used to encrypt it, but you're not storing the either value when you encrypt, and instead generate another (completely different) key/IV during your decrypt routine.

As another answer indicates, you're also forgetting to reverse the text encoding you use when encrypting. I would suggest using `Convert.ToBase64String()` to convert the encrypted data to a string value, and `Convert.FromBase64String()` to convert it back into a byte array when decrypting.